# stripe_test_public_key and stripe_live_public_key tags are not parsing

Tags: subscriptions, stripe

I've installed the DevDemon Subscriptions add-on with EE 2.10.1 and I'm using the Stripe payment gateway.

I'm currently just testing with the default templates that come with the add-on. In the subs/subscribe_stripe template, the publishable API key is included in the form as a hidden field using the {stripe_test_public_key} or {stripe_live_public_key} tag. However, the tag is not being parsed.

I can't even find anywhere in the add-on's files where that tag is being defined.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you tell us what `subs` tag you are using for your tests to pull through this default template? There's no mention of these tags in the [docs](http://www.devdemon.com/documentation/subscriptions/) anywhere, so I'm going out on a limb and guessing these variables are inserted into the globals by Subscriptions when it encounters a subs form, just a guess though. Perhpas you could tell us what you're trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs, it implies you have to 'hard-code' your keys in your template : http://www.devdemon.com/documentation/subscriptions/#subs-payment-gateway-stripe

I realise your reading the default templates however I would guess that if you use a default template via a `subs` tag it'll inject these values into globals, that or they are placeholders with squiggly brackets just to confuse you!

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that in the docs.  Ok, hard-coding it is! thanks